# XmlReader stops at nested while

Tags: c#, xmlreader

I have this xml:

```
<Root>
   <Client>
     <Name>Some Name</Name>
     <Messages>
         <Type name="mail" value="a@a.com"></Type>
         <Type name="chat" value="some-username"></Type>
     </Messages>
   </Client>
   ...................MORE CLIENTS HERE
</Root>
```

I loop through it with xmlreader and It is working as expected.
the problem is when I try to loop on nodes `"<Type"`, this is where the first code get stop.

The code reads the xml correctly, but it stop after the first iteration of the nested while:

```
using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(xmlString), settings))
{
    while (reader.ReadToFollowing("Client"))
    {
         reader.ReadToFollowing("Name");
         var message = reader.ReadElementContentAsString();
         Trace.WriteLine("message: " + message);

         while (reader.ReadToFollowing("Type")){
              var value = reader.GetAttribute("value");
              var name = reader.GetAttribute("name");

         }//everything stops here///
    }
}
```

How can I continue after the first client?
thanks

Comment: Your xml isn't valud, as there's no `</Messages>`  to close the `<Messages>` element. The reader expects to be processing a conformant document by default.

Comment: Thanks, this is just pseudo, fixing it.

Comment: What is the content of the settings value for `XmlReader` ? I tried you code locally (without settings) and it iterates over `<Type>` elements correctly (which means twice)

Comment: IgnoreWhitespace and IgnoreComments are set to true. The problem is that it is not iterating to the next `<Client`. stops at the first one. note my comment (after the while). thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work , the main difference is that :

- ReadToFollowing reads data through the **whole** document which means through all client nodes not just a subtree
- To solve this you need to first read to `Message` element and the create a reader for subtree (`ReadSubtree`) to keep your data withing `Client` node

  ```
  using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(xmlString), settings))
      {
          while (reader.ReadToFollowing("Client"))
          {
              reader.ReadToFollowing("Name");
              var message = reader.ReadElementContentAsString();

              //advance to <Message> element
              reader.ReadToFollowing("Messages");

              //create sub-tree reader to restrict the scope
              var typeReader = reader.ReadSubtree();

              while (typeReader.ReadToFollowing("Type"))
              {
                  var value = reader.GetAttribute("value");
                  var name = reader.GetAttribute("name");
              }//everything stops here///
          }
      }
  ```